# Dropbox API cURL request error: "options: expected array, got string"

Tags: php, curl, dropbox-api, php-curl

I try to make a cURL request to Dropbox API, but I get this error:

> **Error in call to API function "files/search_v2": options: expected array, got string**

I don't understand why, I'm sending an array!?

My code is below. Documentation here: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-search

```
$token = "....";
$options = array("path" => "/", "max_results" => 10);
$options["file_categories"] = "folder";
$parameters = array("query" => "searchPhrase", "options" => $options);

$headers = array(
    "Authorization: Bearer $token",
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$curlOptions = array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($parameters),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
);

try {

    $ch = curl_init('https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/files/search_v2');
    curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOptions);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    //var_dump($response);
    curl_close($ch);

} catch (Exception $e) {

    trigger_error(
        sprintf(
            'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
            $e->getCode(),
            $e->getMessage()
        ),
        E_USER_ERROR
    );
}
```

Comment: try `$options["file_categories"] = ["folder"];`

Comment: That seemed to work!? But I don't understand why?

Comment: check the docs, it says List, which is an array, also categories is plural

Comment: Oh boy, I didn't notice that... Thanks a lot! Feel free to post it as an answer and I will accept it.